# How to remove garbage characters when converting from Bytes Stream/buffer to String?

Tags: c#, string, buffer

Getting string of exact length from non-fixed length buffer of bytes from process memory

I want to read a process(game) memory to get **File Names(string)** of maps the game has currently loaded in the process memory.

The expected string is of no fixed length , the maximum possible value is 37 so i declared the buffer of length 37.

The read part was easy by using Win32 API.

```
byte[] pBuffer = new byte[37];
ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, (int)address, pBuffer, 37, ref read);
```

Here is the code to convert the bytes to string.

```
string map = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pBuffer);
```

The output is fine but the string contains garbage characters hidden from display.

When i tried to open the  file, **FileExist(map)** function return false. The files are there in the folder but i found out that the String.Length is 37 for every string i get from memory.

E.g The file name is **"abc.bms"** and its lenght(String.Lenght) is **37**.

Solution i tried so far :-

```
  // string = string.Substring(0, string.IndexOf('\0'));   
  // string = string.Replace('\0');
  // string = string.Trim();
```

The string length is not correct , i want to remove all those invisible characters from string ?

Comment: Do you just want to remove null chars? `var res = str.Replace("\0", string.Empty);`?

Comment: No , i want all extra characters from the string , i want to compare it with file names in file system. Apparently the string is fine but it has some hidden extra characters that is not giving me correct file path.

Comment: Why do you use ASCII as the encoding? You use the value as a file path, it seems. In the Win32 API, file paths are UTF-16, just like strings are in .NET. If you happen to be using the Windows 95-compatible variants (xxxA) of Win32 functions (which don't support the full character set that NTFS requires [Unicode]) and get a file path with an "ANSI" encoding, you either have to know which specific ANSI encoding it is, or know that it is the same as your thread's current ANSI code page. In that case (and no other), you would use `Encoding.Default`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string in memory is a null-terminated ASCII string, you are probably better off truncating the buffer before you pass it to GetString.

You can find the first 0 (null) in the pBuffer array, allocate a new buffer of N size (where N is the number of bytes before the first 0). Then copy N bytes from pBuffer to your new array and then pass that new array to GetString.

Update: sample code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] x = new byte[] { 55,55,55,93,93,0,23,0};
        var firstNullIndex = Array.FindIndex(x, b => b == 0);

        string s = Encoding.Default.GetString(x, 0, firstNullIndex);
        Console.WriteLine(s);

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is an overload to GetString that takes a count. So just pass pBuffer and N to that overload of GetString.

Comment: can you help me with truncating pBuffer array ? how to search the buffer array and create a new one , 2 code of lines will do that job

Answer (score 0):

```
TrimEnd(new char[] { (char)0 })
```

Check out the link to remove empty Bytes:

[Trim Empty Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402622/string-from-byte-array-doesnt-get-trimmed-in-c)

Seems similar to Wiktor's comment.