# Trim padded values when converting a byte array to String

Tags: c#, string

An external DLL that I'm using in my C# program gives me a pointer to a location in memory. From there, I read in the following 200 bytes at that location to a byte array, and then convert it to a String.

**Problem:** For the most part my code works but it also reads in the values that the DLL used as padding (seems to be 205).

**Attempt:** I tried trimming the string by using examples from this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402622/string-from-byte-array-doesnt-get-trimmed-in-c), but the padding remained. My code is as follows:

```
const int BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME = 200;
const char PADDING_VALUE = (char)205;
const char NULL_VALUE = (char)0;

IntPtr nameAddress = (IntPtr)myDLL.GetPointer();

// Only run if the pointer is not to a null value
if (nameAddress != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    byte[] nameAsBytes = new byte[BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME];
    Marshal.Copy(nameAddress, nameAsBytes, 0, BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME);
    string nameAsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(nameAsBytes).TrimEnd(new char[] { PADDING_VALUE, NULL_VALUE });

    // Add the string to deviceNames, a string array
    deviceNames[n] = nameAsString;
}
```

As seen below, even though I used `TrimEnd()` the string `nameAsString` still ended up containing the null and padded values.

[image: Padded values in a String]

---

I'm currently trying to see if I can find the index of `\0` in my `nameAsBytes` byte array, and only parse the bytes up until that index. But still, what am I doing wrong with `TrimEnd()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the byte array is converted to a .NET string it is in UTF16 encoding, and char(205) won't have the effect you are looking for.  Any value greater than 127 may end up mapping to a different code point post-conversion.

Try removing the 205's *before* converting to a string.

```
const int BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME = 200;
const char PADDING_VALUE = (char)205;
const char NULL_VALUE = (char)0;

IntPtr nameAddress = (IntPtr)myDLL.GetPointer();

// Only run if the pointer is not to a null value
if (nameAddress != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    byte[] nameAsBytes = new byte[BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME];
    Marshal.Copy(nameAddress, nameAsBytes, 0, BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME);
    byte[] cleanedBytes = nameAsBytes.Where(a => a != PADDING_VALUE); //Filter out the bad bytes
    string nameAsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cleanedBytes);

    // Add the string to deviceNames, a string array
    deviceNames[n] = nameAsString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UTF8Encoding.GetString Method (Byte[], Int32, Int32) method : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzb9f993(v=vs.110).aspx

```
byte[] nameAsBytes = new byte[BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME];
Marshal.Copy(nameAddress, nameAsBytes, 0, BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME);
int strlen;
for (strlen = 0; strlen < nameAsBytes.Length;strlen++)
{
  if (nameAsBytes[strlen] == 0)
    break;
}
string nameAsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(nameAsBytes, 0, strlen);
```